# Clustering Algorithm for data where each type has multiple observations?

Tags: clustering, multilevel-analysis, k-nearest-neighbour, games

I am trying to segment football teams based on their playing style using multiple features. I want to see which football teams have similar playing styles using cluster algorithms.

For each team I have ~ 15 observations of their performance, and there are 15 teams so I have about 225 observations.

My understanding of KNN is that it will treat each observation as its own type (ie assume that when it places a point in a group, it doesn't necessarily place another point in a group). So for example, one 49ers game could be placed  in group A and another 49ers game could be placed in group B.

How do I modify the algorithm/find another clustering algorithm that looks at all the data, and if it say places the 49ers in group A, then it is placing all the 49ers games in group A. Then it would partition the groups that minimizes some loss function similar to KNN.

Any suggestions would be very helpful!

Comment: can you make your 15 games into 15 features?

Comment: Then it would blow up dimensionality, because for each game I'm using 4-5 features. Also, the order of the games is irrelevant to me for this purpose, but if I were to do this then the order would matter. (IE if 49ers scored a lot of points in their 3rd game vs 4th game, this could impact which cluster they're placed in.)

Comment: typical clustering algos work on samples, and group them into clusters. so to use them you need to make each team a sample of its own. I'm not sure why would you say that the order of games become important in such setup. in fact, to contrary you'd have to make extra effort to insert the order into features,